# How can I query Cassandra without knowing what I'm going to find?

Tags: cassandra

Just typing that title makes me wonder if I'm in a dimension where everything I've every know about databases is wrong.

I have [several tables but this is an example]:

```
CREATE TABLE stream (
  source_id uuid,
  yyyymmdd int,
  event_type text,
  time timestamp,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((source_id, yyyymmdd, event_type), time)
)
```

I have an idea of what might be in `yyyymmdd` but for the other partition keys, I do not. Without knowing what the possible values for source_id and event_type are, I can't query it. What I ultimately want to know is:

What is the oldest `yyyymmdd` and the newest `yyyymmdd` in the db?

It's almost like I need a database of what is in my database.

Comment: What is your use case? Do you want to search the whole table? That can be done with paging. What you're describing is a direct query where you know the partition key but at the same time you don't, that's not possible.

Comment: My use case is that I have copied the cluster and I want to know if the new cluster has everything it is supposed to. Rather than compare every single record, I'd setting for comparing the records with the MAX and MIN values of `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: I don't know any easy way to do this. I would make a client that goes through all data with paging and saves the min and max of yyyymmdd for both clusters. Might take some time but it's the only way I can think of right now.

Comment: I don't know how big your dataset is, but maybe this would work: export yyyymmdd column to csv using copy command and then find out your min and max values. Also, throttle the copy command using NUMPROCESSES and MAXREQUESTS since it will eat up a lot of resources.

Comment: @Horia if you wrote that up with actual code I'd accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In cqlsh go to your keyspace (`use <keyspace_name>`) and run

```
copy stream(yyyymmdd) to 'stream-yyyymmdd.csv' with NUMPROCESSES = 1 and MAXREQUESTS = 1;
```

Or prefix the table name in the copy command with keyspace_name (< keyspace_name>.stream) if you don't want to run `use <keyspace_name>`.

For NUMPROCESSES and MAXREQUESTS you can use the values that suits you. Please refer to COPY documentatation [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html). NUMPROCESSES is number of worker processes. Maximum value is 16. Default value: -1. MAXREQUESTS is maximum number of requests each worker can process in parallel. Default value: 6.

Afterwards do a sort and extract first and last line

```
sort -n -o stream-yyyymmdd-sorted.csv stream-yyyymmdd.csv
head -1 stream-yyyymmdd-sorted.csv
tail -1 stream-yyyymmdd-sorted.csv
```

HTH

Comment: My friend, you are on your way to a very high Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange reputation. This is a very good answer.